# jquery datatable with ajax based pagination

Tags: ajax, pagination, datatables

I have javascript function that populates datatable using Ajax. My javascript code looks like :

```
 $('#results').dataTable({
    // Ajax load data
    "ajax": {
        "url": "get_intl_tickets",
        "type": "POST",
        "data": {
            "user_id": 451,
            "csrfmiddlewaretoken" : csrftoken,
        }
    }
 })
```

My server side script in django has a function that loads around 500 data rows. Now the problem is that I don't want to load whole data at a time. Instead I want to have first 10 data rows. Then with pagination, another 10 rows like that. 
I read the page [server side processing](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html) documentation of datatables. I tried with `"serverSide": true` option as well. I am not understanding server side script. There is given an example of PHP. It seems that they are not using any parameters like `draw, recordsFiltered, recordsTotal` there. There they have used php SSP class. And it is unknown what does it do. I am trying to implement it in django.

But I am not finding proper good documentation to implement. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Old question but one I also had a surprisingly difficult time finding an answer to, so in case anyone else ends up here... :P

I found this 2020 article very helpful, specifically part 6 showing the "complete code" that includes getting the correct variables, building the SQL query, and how to build/structure the data object that it responds with:
https://makitweb.com/datatables-ajax-pagination-with-search-and-sort-php/

Their example posted below:

```
<?php
## Database configuration
include 'config.php';

## Read value
$draw = $_POST['draw'];
$row = $_POST['start'];
$rowperpage = $_POST['length']; // Rows display per page
$columnIndex = $_POST['order'][0]['column']; // Column index
$columnName = $_POST['columns'][$columnIndex]['data']; // Column name
$columnSortOrder = $_POST['order'][0]['dir']; // asc or desc
$searchValue = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['search']['value']); // Search value

## Search 
$searchQuery = " ";
if($searchValue != ''){
   $searchQuery = " and (emp_name like '%".$searchValue."%' or 
        email like '%".$searchValue."%' or 
        city like'%".$searchValue."%' ) ";
}

## Total number of records without filtering
$sel = mysqli_query($con,"select count(*) as allcount from employee");
$records = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sel);
$totalRecords = $records['allcount'];

## Total number of record with filtering
$sel = mysqli_query($con,"select count(*) as allcount from employee WHERE 1 ".$searchQuery);
$records = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sel);
$totalRecordwithFilter = $records['allcount'];

## Fetch records
$empQuery = "select * from employee WHERE 1 ".$searchQuery." order by ".$columnName." ".$columnSortOrder." limit ".$row.",".$rowperpage;
$empRecords = mysqli_query($con, $empQuery);
$data = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($empRecords)) {
   $data[] = array( 
      "emp_name"=>$row['emp_name'],
      "email"=>$row['email'],
      "gender"=>$row['gender'],
      "salary"=>$row['salary'],
      "city"=>$row['city']
   );
}

## Response
$response = array(
  "draw" => intval($draw),
  "iTotalRecords" => $totalRecords,
  "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $totalRecordwithFilter,
  "aaData" => $data
);

echo json_encode($response);
```

Answer (score 1):

Nice exemple: 
https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/defer_loading.html

But you need edit server side.
Response demo

{
    draw:2,
    recordsFiltered:57,
    recordsTotal:57
}

Comment: Can you please give me an example of server side script ? That is the main thing I am not understanding. They have given an example of PHP. It seems that they are not using any parameters like `draw, recordsFiltered, recordsTotal` there. I am trying to implement it in django.

Comment: have you found any solution ?